# Extract all numbers from string that matches pattern

Tags: python, python-3.5, jython-2.7

For example:

```
String = "geod rfff eef 234_1538 ffgg df 134774  234_1645"
```

I want to extract only `234_1538` and `234_1645`, not the remaining patterns.
I tried using `Re.search` but it returns only the first match.

Comment: Did you try `Re.findall?`

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what you want to consider a "match" or not, so I've made the assumption to consider any continuous series of digits with an underscore somewhere in the middle a match.

To find all matches in a string, you can use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall). Here's a demo:

```
import re

s = "geod rfff eef 234_1538 ffgg df 134774  234_1645"

print(re.findall('\d+_\d+', s))
```

**Output**

```
['234_1538', '234_1645']
```